# Vuetify 2.1 V-Select reset or clear selection after change

Tags: vuetify.js, v-select

i have to fix a vuetify custom component that extends from Vue Class and includes a V-Select component. The dropdown is working fine but since its just a trigger pad to pop open modals the requirement is to reset/clear the dropdown selection after onchange event. basically i think i need to trigger the clearableCallback but i am not sure how to do it. First of all i have the problem that when i bind a method from the parent component the scope is always the parent so this refers to the extend parent component class. so i wonder how to get into the scope of the v-select component. i can not see apart from the clearable prop there is no native functionality for what i am trying to do. any hints? thanks

Comment: Set the `v-model` value of the `v-select` to `-1`?

Comment: makes sense. was not aware of the binding capabilities

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but if I do, you may try using @change event on the v-select and use a method in which you open modals and reset the value of the v-select model to any desired one.

```
<v-select 
    v-model="select"
    @change="someMethod"
>
</v-select>

...

methods: {
    someMethod(){
        this.openModal(this.select);
        this.select = 0;
}
```

Comment: yes that works. didnt know that the value had to be 0. i have multiple v-selects inside a data table and so the reset works only for the first change event.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the value to 0 only worked for the first change for me. Every subsequent change did not reset the displayed value. The only thing that worked consistently for me was using `$nextTick`. e.g.

```
onInput() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.select = 0;
    });
}
```

It seems to be something to do with vuetify's internal implementation, and the `lazyValue` getting out of sync with the `value` prop.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. I also could set the model value to `null` with this method, not just `0` like other answers suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As I far understand your question. The solution could be using the ref key in the v-select element and call the reset() function.
For example

In HTML

```
<v-select @change="handleOnSelectChange"
           ref="selectedEl"/>
```

In vue methods

```
methods:{ handleOnSelectChange:function(){this.$refs["selectedEl"].reset();}}
```